# KDE theme in Ubuntu Unity

Tags: unity, kde, themes

I would like to know if it is possible to have a KDE theme (I think it's called Oxygen, but I'm not sure) for Ubuntu Unity? I really like the theme used in KDE but I prefer to use Ubuntu Unity. I wonder if anyone have tried that.

Thanks.

@chathurawidanage: i followed your instruction and installed oxygen-transparent successfully. However, I was not able to find the theme among the list in System Settings -> Appearance. There is no application appearance. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. I also tried using Ubuntu Tweak but only the icon is available on the option. Any other way to activate this theme?

Comment: oxygen-transparent is for KDE/qt apps, not GTK, so you won't be able to use it with Unity, you can use it for ie. dolphin, amarok, etc. oxygen-gtk is for GTK apps (firefox, nautilus,etc).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [this](http://hugo-kde.blogspot.com/2010/11/oxygen-gtk.html) is what you need. A gtk port of a kde theme. You will require gtk supported engine and it seems [oxygen](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/?content=136216) supports both gtk2 and gtk3. There seems to be a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~hrvojes/+archive/kde-goodies) providing the required theme as well as engine. You may use it as well or search for other ppa in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas). Just do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hrvojes/kde-goodies
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen oxygen-transparent
```

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Thanks so much! Its what I'm looking and its actually awesome except that it doesn't have its own widow decorations. Also, when I set the theme in Ubuntu Tweak (cant set it in System Settings -> Appearance, Oxygen-gtk does not show there as an option), I no longer was able to open any application. I tried restarting my computer and logging in using Ubuntu or Gnome, but nothing shows, even right clicking the desktop. Good thing I have Fluxbox installed to reset the theme and uninstall gtkN-engines-oxygen and oxygen-transparent. Any idea why that happened? I would actually like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need git to get the sources for oxygen-transparent.  You’ll need some other packages too.  Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake kdelibs5-dev kdebase-workspace-dev libxrender-dev libx11-dev
```

Now, since you’ve still got your terminal open, let’s finish the job.  Get the sources like this:

git clone git://anongit.kde.org/oxygen-transparent

Now, navigate to the directory you’ve downloaded:

```
cd oxygen-transparent
```

Almost there kids. Let’s run the setup script.

```
./oxygen-setup.pl
```

Getting closer…

```
sudo make && make install
```

Provided there were no errors, you should be able to use this immediately. Just open up System Settings and go to Application Appearance. Click Style and find Widget Style. Select Oxygen Transparent and click Apply at the bottom.

Now, click on Configure.  Lower your Opacity to a level that’s comfortable for you to look at all the time.  Hit OK as the bottom of the window, and you are all done?