# Oxygen-gtk theme on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, themes, gtk, oxygen

I tried to use the oxygen-gtk theme on ubuntu 12.04, but it didn't work properly, only the menus. The windows looked like win95/98 :D
I know that the best way to use that is to use Kubuntu, but I found it really buggy...
So, is there a way to use that theme on Unity?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found something similar, a person with the same problem as you asked this question a while ago. Check it out here: [KDE theme in Ubuntu Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104635/kde-theme-in-ubuntu-unity) , if it helps.

Enjoy Ubuntu!